# Convert string of lists into list of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.7, nested-lists

I'm trying to convert a list of lists passed as string to nested list in `python-3.7.5` and I'm missing something. I tried `ast` but it seems to be throwing an encoding error.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ast
sample="[1abcd245,2bcdasdf,3jakdshfkh234234],[234asdfmnkk234]"
print(ast.literal_eval(sample))
```

```
ERROR:

    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [1abcd245,2bcdasdf,3jakdshfkh234234],[234asdfmnkk234]
```

```
Required output:
[[1abcd245,2bcdasdf,3jakdshfkh234234],[234asdfmnkk234]]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `eval()` function here, after making two changes to your starting string:

1. Wrap each list item in double quotes
2. Wrap the entire input in `[...]` to make it a formal 2D list

```py
sample = "[1abcd245,2bcdasdf,3jakdshfkh234234],[234asdfmnkk234]"
sample = '[' + re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'"\1"', sample) + ']'
list = eval(sample)
print(list)
```

This prints:

```
[['1abcd245', '2bcdasdf', '3jakdshfkh234234'], ['234asdfmnkk234']]
```

Comment: Feels like your answer is the closest I could get. Was hoping ast might have solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that `literal_eval` is unable to parse the strings within the `sample` you provide. I was able to get the output you wanted by adding a triple quote to surround the sample string, adding quotes to each string within the lists and adding an extra set of brackets:

```
import ast
sample="""[["1abcd245","2bcdasdf","3jakdshfkh234234"],["234asdfmnkk234"]]"""
print(ast.literal_eval(sample))
```

In the case you cannot change the input I would recommend using the `json` library:

```
import json
json.loads(sample)
```

Which on my machine gets the desired result!

Comment: I cannot change the input, here.

Comment: `if sample= "[1abcd245,2bcdasdf,3jakdshfkh234234],[234asdfmnkk234]"`, then json.loads also errors out. 
Error: 

`File "python-3.7.5/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "python-3.7.5/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "python-3.7.5/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`

Comment: I see, that's my bad I was using the altered version of the input, why are you unable to modify the input?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
sample="[1abcd245,2bcdasdf,3jakdshfkh234234],[234asdfmnkk234]"
l1 = []
for item in sample.split(","):
    if item.startswith('['):
        l1.append([])
        l1[-1].append(item[1:])
    elif item.endswith(']'):
        l1[-1].append(item[:-2])
    else:
        l1[-1].append(item)


print(l1)
```